# Assembly - Move bit from 32bit value to 5bit variable

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, att

I have value storaged in 32bit register eax, it's #17 bit of some number (0x00020000).
I want to create 5 bit variable and put this bit in it.
How can I do this?
I'm using AT&T syntax.

Comment: As I said in my other answer, shift it right. The "5 bit variable" isn't clear.

Comment: Variable, which takes 5 bits of memory.

Comment: On x86, you can't allocate less than 1 byte. You can of course pack bitfields there, but the solution is the same anyway - shift your bit to the proper place, and if necessary, use bitwise `OR` to write it.

Comment: Thank you. :) I was thinking is this even possible.

Comment: Just got brain image of an assembler that wasn't byte aligned! ...*twitch* *twitch*